# Django performing an action on a model via link

Tags: django, url

I want to, say, delete a record via a button on a website. How would I do that?

Thus far every "button" or action I've done has to do with forms, which is handled via "post". The URL would stay the same, just a matter if it's a get or a post that the content and actions are different.

But if I want to delete something, I really don't think I want to create a URL that's like "/delete_record" or something like that. Also, don't really think every button needs to be a form either.... say there are 10 records and I could delete any one of them, that'd be like 10 forms?

Maybe this is something I'd do with Javascript or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a url with an identifier to the object you want to delete and in the view, just delete the object.

Say you want to delete an object of the `Record` type. Create an url like so

```
url(r'^record/delete/(?P<id>)/$', 'delete_record_view', name='delete-record-url')
```

A view like so

```
def delete_record_view(request, id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Record, pk=id)
    # some validation here to make sure the user clicking the link can delete the object
    obj.delete()
```

And in the template

```
<a href="{% url 'record-delete-link' record_object.id %}">Delete</a>
```

Comment: I take it this is a "reverse" URL feature in Django? I didn't know this existed.... is this the right doc for what you're using? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls

Comment: Yes. More on this in the built in template tags documentation - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url